# confusing when Hermitian conjugation involve with time ordering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions

I encounter a problem when I try to calculate the Hermitian conjugation about a correlation function. For example the propagator of free real scale field
$$\tag{1}\langle0|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|0\rangle = \frac{\delta}{i\delta J(x_1)}\frac{\delta}{i\delta J(x_2)}Z(J)|_{J=0}$$

where $J$ is source, $Z(J) = \text{exp}[i W(J)]$, $W(J)$ is the sum of all connected diagrams except the vacuum diagrams, and it's real for free-field, $Z(0) = 1$, ([Srednicki](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html) Page 65). So
$$\tag{2}
-i \langle0|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|0\rangle = \frac{\delta}{i\delta J(x_1)}\frac{\delta}{i\delta J(x_2)}W(J)|_{J=0}
$$
The Hermitian conjugation of Eq.2 is
$$\tag{3}
\frac{\delta}{i\delta J(x_2)}\frac{\delta}{i\delta J(x_1)}W(J)|_{J=0}
$$
since the field is real. Compare with Eq.2 the difference is just exchange $x_1\leftrightarrow x_2$. The only Lorentz invariant scalar is $(x_1 - x_2)^2$ in this case, so exchange $x_1\leftrightarrow x_2$ doesn't change any thing, Eq.2 is unchanged under Hermitian conjugation
$$\tag{4}\langle0|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|0\rangle^\dagger = -\langle0|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|0\rangle.$$

However, one can also write Eq.1 as
$$\tag{5}\langle0|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|0\rangle = \langle0|\,\theta(x_1^0 - x_2^0)\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2) + \theta(x_2^0-x_1^0)\phi(x_2)\phi(x_1)\,|0\rangle.$$
Where $\theta(t)$ is step function. Under charge conjuation, the
$$\tag{6} -i\langle0|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|0\rangle = -i\langle0|\,\theta(x_1^0 - x_2^0)\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2) + \theta(x_2^0-x_1^0)\phi(x_2)\phi(x_1)\,|0\rangle$$

becomes to
$$\tag{7}i\langle0|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|0\rangle^\dagger = i\langle0|\,\theta(x_1^0 - x_2^0)\phi(x_2)\phi(x_1) + \theta(x_2^0-x_1^0)\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\,|0\rangle$$
for real scalar field. It's unclear how to relate above to Eq.5 . However, if we commute $\phi(x_1)$ and $\phi(x_2)$ in R.H.S of Eq.7, it becomes
$$\tag{8}\langle0|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|0\rangle^\dagger = \langle0|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|0\rangle$$
by Eq.5 . Compare with Eq.2, they differ by a sign, which confusing me for a long time.

Again consider the free real scalar propagator
$$\tag{9}\langle0|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|0\rangle = \int\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{i e^{-ik(x_1 - x_2)}}{k^2 - m^2 + i \epsilon}.$$
Under Hermitian conjugation, it becomes
$$\tag{10}\langle0|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|0\rangle^\dagger = \int\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{-i e^{ik(x_1 - x_2)}}{k^2 - m^2 - i \epsilon}.$$
Replace $k\rightarrow -k$, the difference of Eq.12 and Eq.11 is than an overall sign and the sign of $i\epsilon$. When $k^2\neq m^2$, the $i\epsilon$ can be ignore. So it seems that Eq.4 is more correct.

I think the problem may relevant to the time ordering. For example
$$\tag{11}T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}=\begin{cases}\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2),\ x_1^0>x_2^0\\ \phi(x_2)\phi(x_1),\ x_2^0>x_1^0 \end{cases}.$$

Under Hermitian conjugation, in general case, the above becomes
$$\tag{12}T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}^\dagger=\begin{cases}\phi(x_2)^\dagger\phi(x_1)^\dagger,\ x_1^0>x_2^0\\ \phi(x_1)^\dagger\phi(x_2)^\dagger,\ x_2^0>x_1^0 \end{cases}$$
since $\phi$ is real.

While
$$\tag{13}T\{(\,\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\,)^\dagger\}=T\{\phi(x_2)^\dagger \phi(x_1)^\dagger\}=\begin{cases}\phi(x_1)^\dagger\phi(x_2)^\dagger,\ x_1^0>x_2^0\\ \phi(x_2)^\dagger\phi(x_1)^\dagger,\ x_2^0>x_1^0 \end{cases}.$$

So we have
$$
\tag{14}T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}^\dagger \neq T\{(\,\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\,)^\dagger\}.
$$

Thus the two operations, time ordering and Hermitian conjugation, may subtler than I think. However, I still don't know where I made mistake between Eq.4 to Eq.8